# Why is this string property shown to be fully covered when it's not supposed to be?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Program();
        Console.Write(x.Text);
        Console.Write(x.Num);
        //Console.Write(x.Num);//line A
    }

    private string Text_;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return Text_ ?? (Text_ = "hello");//line B
        }
    }

    private int? Num_;
    public int Num
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(Num_ ?? (Num_ = 42));//line C
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to get code coverage results. It shows that line B is totally covered while line C is partially covered. I would expect that line B is partially covered as well instead of being totally covered. **Why is it the case that the code coverage results shows line B as being totally covered?**

To demonstrate that it's working "correctly" for Num property, uncomment line A and run the coverage. It should show line C as totally being covered.

When I rewrite the code to a more verbose form (see below), it works correctly and reports that Text_ is partially covered. I prefer to use the former for its brevity, and would like to know if the two forms are equivalent too. Thanks in advance.

```
if (Text_ != null)
{
    return Text_;
}
else
{
    return Text_ = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `??` on `Nullable<T>` expands to something more complex at the compiler, i.e.

```
a ?? b
```

is really

```
a.HasValue ? a.GetValueOrDefault() : b
```

Now, since `a` was null/empty for the only time it was executed, the `a.GetValueOrDefault()` has never been called. The underlying code when using a string (or any flat reference) is simpler.

In reality, just call it twice to make this go away:

```
Console.Write(x.Text); // first call; performs init
Console.Write(x.Text); // test once initialized
Console.Write(x.Num); // first call; performs init
Console.Write(x.Num); // test once initialized
```

Comment: Got it. I should have gone deeper into the syntactic sugar I used, and my premise is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the IL generated by this line I'd suspect that the compiler has done some internal optimisation that causes your "line B" to be regarded as a single statement.

The principal difference between the two statements is that line B refers to an object, whereas line C uses a shorthand reference to `Num_.Value`.

---

In general, it's definitely not worth getting stressed about "100% code coverage" -- as this example indicates, sometimes the instrumentation is wrong, anyway. What's important is that *most* of the code is covered, at least the principal execution paths through business logic.

Coverage is no replacement for code reviews by another human.

Comment: Indeed it's not worth getting stressed about 100% coverage which is what my boss wants, so I intend to justify myself for parts which I cannot cover. If it is not accepted, I wouldn't accept working here much longer too.